# Flash game based on the 2004 TV series Lost about staying alive on the island

Tags: story-identification, video-games, lost

I'm looking for a flash game which I played on the Internet some time between 2004 and 2010, based on the events of the [2004 TV series Lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_(2004_TV_series)).

The idea was that we are one of the survivors of the plane that crashed on the island, and we had to stay alive. There were items lying around which we could pick up for that, such as a box of knives, some pills to regain stamina, an empty bottle of water, etc. Clicking on them would add them to the inventory. During the entire game, we didn't encounter any other survivor.

We could move around the island by moving the mouse around and clicking in some spot of the game, although I cannot remember if it involved clicking on an arrow or in the corners. Some areas I remember:

- There was some place in the forest where we could click on a wire on the ground. There would be some strange grass/leaves noises, and then the screen would be upside down. By clicking again, we would be redirected to the game over screen, which probably was a picture of the TV series. It was yellow toned and showed us 2 graves on the beach.
- Another area in the forest had a wild boar running around, which we could fight by throwing knives, assuming we picked up the box of knives. Otherwise, when the boar attacked us, it would show its face covering the entire screen as we take damage. I managed to defeat it once, and it was added into the inventory, although I wasn't entirely sure what purpose it served.
- By going deeper into the forest, we could also reach the hatch with the number "4 8 15 16 23 42" written on it, although I was never able to open it.
- Some other place had a crashed plane. When we entered it, there was a radio. Clicking on it would zoom on it, and we could hear a voice talking, although I was too young to determine the spoken language.

I think the character's health/stamina was depicted as a gauge which decreased over time, and when it was depleted, we were sent to the game over screen. Taking damage such as when you get attacked by the wild boar would also deplete it.

When I tried looking around, I stumbled upon the game [Lostscape](https://lostpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Lostscape) which seems to have some level of similarities. But the game I played didn't include videos playing when clicking on items, as far as I can remember.

Comment: I think one of my relatives had told me the wire was a nod to some woman living on the island, making deadly traps.